# Invoke callback passed down from parent component within an event handler, then reassign variable to a certain value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, variable-assignment

Essentially, I want to invoke a callback passed down from a parent component then reassign a value. I've tried creating a class method that invokes the given callback function from the parent components props, but I'm getting an infinite loop with setState. On another method that I tried but cannot seem to replicate at the moment, an error was thrown that stated `"callback is not a function"`.

Perhaps, I'm phrasing this in a weird way. Here's an example:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { parentState: true }

    this._handleToggle = this._handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  _handleToggle() {
    this.setState({ parentState: !this.state.parentState })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent
        onSomeEvent={this._handleToggle}
      />
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.randomInteger = 8;

    this._invokeCallback = this._invokeCallback.bind(this);
  }

  // this is where I'm having trouble
  _invokeCallback(callback) {

    callback();
    this.randomInteger = 0;
  }

  render() {
    const { onSomeEvent } = this.props;

    // Error 
    return (
      <button onClick={this._invokeCallback(onSomeEvent)} />
    )
  }
}
```

What I want from here is to reassign `this.randomInteger` to a certain value AFTER invoking the callback that was handed down from the parent component. What can I do from here?

I apologize if my example is missing some pieces or is incomplete. I am rushing to write this up. Please feel free to correct any mistakes I made in my phrasing or example code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **_invokeCallback** is executing immediately.

Due to the parentheses and passing an argument here `this._invokeCallback(onSomeEvent)`, you are setting **onClick** to the result of the **_invokeCallback** method.

This is what is causing the infinite loop where **setState** in the parent causes a re-render in the child which then executes **_invokeCallback** again, and so on.

You could use an anonymous function with **onClick** so that **_invokeCallback** is only executed when the button is clicked:

```
render() {
  const { onSomeEvent } = this.props

  return (
    <button onClick={ () => this._invokeCallback(onSomeEvent) } />
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you could call the **onSomeEvent** function from the **_invokeCallback** method:

```
_invokeCallback() {
  this.props.onSomeEvent()
  this.randomInteger = 0
}

render() { 
  return (
    <button onClick={ this._invokeCallback } />
  )
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad this helped you out.